# Как сделать коммит из нескольких измененный файлов

Tags: git

В процессе работы, возникают ситуации:

например я работаю с компонентов оформления заказа на сайте, уже успел изменить много файлов, но еще не сделал коммит. И сразу возникает необходимость внести несколько правок в файлы другого модуля. Хочется разделить комиты одного модуля и другого.

Как нужно действовать в таких ситуациях ? Обязательно ли мне нужно сделать коммит текущих файлов (оформления заказа), а только потом внести изменения в другой модуль ? Или есть другие варианты ?

Comment: Добавлю важное уточнение:

вариант сделать коммит первого модуля, а только потом  с другим модулем работать не совсем подходит, т.к. изменения в текущем модуле, доделаны.

Comment: Нужно сделать коммит из 2-3 файлов среди всех изменений.

Comment: Вы в одной ветке что ли все делаете?

Comment: `$ man git-stash`

Comment: добавь несколь файлов (или даже их чачтей) с помощью `git add`, а потом закоммить `git commit`'ом

Comment: Вопрос вообще непонятен. Делайте как нравится. Хоть всё сразу, хоть помодульно, хоть по одному файлу на коммит.

Comment: Во-первых, построить процесс с использованием `git worktree ...`. Во-вторых, в описанной ситуации можно подойти разными вариантами: 1) `git stash ...` текущего состояния, потом вернуться к нему; 2) `git commit -a; git branch ...; git checkout ...; git reset --hard HEAD~1` закомитить всё, создать новую ветку, потом откатиться на старую и снести в ней последний комит; 3) `git commit --interactive` если часть внесённых изменений нужна в разных комитах, повторять, пока ничего не останется в staging.